# Trigger Google Home listening with pysical button maybe via network from a Raspberry Pi/Ardruino/etc

Tags: api, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assist-api

I need to trigger the google asistant on my google home (mini) by using a physical button.
I was thinking it may would work by using a Pi or something like that and then pingin it via some api or by creating a addon for the assistan ( i forgot what they are called right now).
Someone got any ideas how i could get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to trigger the Assistant on a Home device except by speaking the hotword to it.

So one solution would be to create hardware that played audio with your voice that says "Hey Google".

You can, however, use the [Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) to create a device that speaks to the Assistant directly. But this won't trigger anything on your Home device.